# fail to "roslaunch pi_tracker skeleton.launch"

Tags: ros, pi-tracker, skeleton

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm not able to "roslaunch pi_tracker skeleton.launch"

## SUMMARY

PARAMETERS

- /use_sim_time
- /skeleton_tracker/fixed_frame
- /skeleton_tracker/load_filepath
- /skeleton_tracker/holonomic
- /skeleton_tracker/skel_to_joint_map/right_shoulder
- /skeleton_tracker/tracking_rate
- /skeleton_tracker/skel_to_joint_map/right_hip
- /skeleton_tracker/command_rate
- /skeleton_tracker/skel_to_joint_map/left_foot
- /skeleton_tracker/skel_to_joint_map/left_elbow
- /skeleton_tracker/skel_to_joint_map/right_foot
- /skeleton_tracker/use_real_robot
- /skeleton_tracker/skel_to_joint_map/right_knee
- /skeleton_tracker/skel_to_joint_map/left_shoulder
- /skeleton_tracker/scale_drive_speed
- /skeleton_tracker/base_controller_rate
- /skeleton_tracker/skel_to_joint_map/left_knee
- /skeleton_tracker/base_control_side
- /rosdistro
- /robot_description
- /skeleton_tracker/skel_to_joint_map/head
- /skeleton_tracker/max_rotation_speed
- /rosversion
- /skeleton_tracker/skel_to_joint_map/torso
- /skeleton_tracker/skel_to_joint_map/right_hand
- /skeleton_tracker/skel_to_joint_map/right_elbow
- /skeleton_tracker/default_joint_speed
- /skeleton_tracker/max_drive_speed
- /skeleton_tracker/scale_rotation_speed
- /robot_state_publisher/publish_frequency
- /skeleton_tracker/reverse_rotation
- /skeleton_tracker/skel_to_joint_map/neck
- /skeleton_tracker/skel_to_joint_map/left_hand
- /skeleton_tracker/joint_controller_rate
- /skeleton_tracker/skel_to_joint_map/left_hip

NODES
/
robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/state_publisher)
kinect_base_link (tf/static_transform_publisher)
kinect_base_link1 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
kinect_base_link2 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
kinect_base_link3 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
skeleton_tracker (pi_tracker/skeleton_tracker)
base_world_broadcaster (tf/static_transform_publisher)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [28728]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 9cae2868-dddc-11e0-9c14-00256438dd8a
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [28741]
started core service [/rosout]
process[robot_state_publisher-2]: started with pid [28748]
process[kinect_base_link-3]: started with pid [28750]
process[kinect_base_link1-4]: started with pid [28756]
process[kinect_base_link2-5]: started with pid [28757]
process[kinect_base_link3-6]: started with pid [28760]
process[skeleton_tracker-7]: started with pid [28770]
process[base_world_broadcaster-8]: started with pid [28776]

[skeleton_tracker-7] process has died [pid 28770, exit code -11].
log files: /home/yuanwei/.ros/log/9cae2868-dddc-11e0-9c14-00256438dd8a/skeleton_tracker-7*.log

Any ideas to solve this? Do I need change anything in the SamplesConfig.xml or skeleton.launch?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11190/fail-to-%22roslaunch-pi_tracker-skeleton.launch%22/) by [ychua](https://answers.ros.org/users/1060/ychua/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2011-09-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ychua](https://answers.ros.org/users/1060/ychua/) on 2011-09-13**:
I've also inserted  in the SampleConfig.xml. But I have the same error [skeleton_tracker-7] process has died [pid 28770, exit code -11]

**Comment by [ychua](https://answers.ros.org/users/1060/ychua/) on 2011-09-13**:
[roscpp_internal] [2011-09-14 09:00:13,929] [thread 0xb2c14790]: [DEBUG] UDPROS server listening on port [42855]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-09-14 09:00:13,933] [thread 0xb2c14790]: [DEBUG] Started node [/skeleton_tracker], pid [882], bound on [yuanwei-desktop], xmlrpc port [45499], tcpros port [33642], logging to [/home/yuanwei/.ros/log/e6c36702-de6c-11e0-9b50-00256438dd8a/skeleton_tracker-7.log], using [real] time
[roscpp_internal] [2011-09-14 09:00:14,196] [thread 0xb2c07b70]: [DEBUG] Accepted connection on socket [7], new socket [16]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-09-14 09:00:14,197] [thread 0xb2c07b70]: [DEBUG] TCPROS received a connection from [10.217.130.120:33589]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-09-14 09:00:14,197] [thread 0xb2c07b70]: [DEBUG] Connection: Creating TransportSubscriberLink for topic [/rosout] connected to [callerid=[/rosout] address=[TCPROS connection to [10.217.130.120:33589 on socket 16]]]                                                                                                   Here's  the log file but I'm still not sure what's wrong

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-09-12**:
Note: "process has died [pid 28770, exit code -11]. log files: /home/yuanwei/.ros/log/9cae2868-dddc-11e0-9c14-00256438dd8a/skeleton_tracker-7*.log" --> please check this file (and post it if you need more help).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's solved now. I just svn checkout http://pi-robot-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pi_tracker. And it just mysteriously worked!

---

Originally posted by [ychua](https://answers.ros.org/users/1060/ychua/) with karma: 71 on 2011-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1